What type of curve is this? Elastica or Logarithmic/Golden Spiral curve?
Does anyone know how to graph the curve below?
Possible curves:

Elastica curve with $0<  k < k1 = 0.65222....$ here? Do I need to know ODE to work with this type?
Golden or Logarithmic Spiral

All I could come up with is a Cartesian graph of $log(x)$ for a portion of it.  The curve appears non-functional, so am guessing it requires a parametric equation ${\bf r(t)} = (f(t), g(t))$ I don't know where to start. Also if it’s a spiral I, not sure how it changes directions.
The image is of Coptic/Egyptian 'G'.

Original:


A part of the S shaped curve may resemble the log curve. But a similar curve is not the same curve. Can you use intrinsic/natural ode equations? Whewell's type? Relates arc length and tangent rotation. One should play with constants.

I'm also considering a start of a logarithmic or golden spiral, but then the curve changes

I’m wondering if this curve is one of Elastica here https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/linteaire/linteaire.shtml#:%7E:text=The%20elastic%20curves%20are%20the%20plane

@YvesDaoust o<k<.65?

Comment:
A part of the S shaped curve may resemble the log curve. But similar curves are always not the same.
Differential equation of an Elastica is derived using Euler-Bernoulli Law by linking curvature and bending moment:
$$ F\cdot y = M = -EI \phi^{'} $$
Prime denotes differentiation w.r.t. arc $s$, $\phi$ is slope angle of the curve tangent.
Since $(F,M, EI)$ are constants we may write further
$$ \sin \phi = -a^2 \phi^{''}, y^{'}= \sin \phi,x^{'} = \cos \phi; $$
Integration using arbitrary boundary conditions results in sine like curves, some even self intersecting progressive and regressive loops.
Physically the loops can be realized by flexible fiberglass wires in the $(x,y)$ plane.
Elastica theory Intro
You can explore a plethora of curves and their originating odes for example in:
2D curves ref

Thanks for helping.  I'm on Calc III right now, I'm assuming ODE is next to learn.  Will I need this to understand curve above?  Also, I have a question on a similar curve here, is it also Elastica maybe requiring DiffEq? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979517/is-this-an-elastica-or-logarithmic-curve-pictured-here

So until then keep up your interest in curves and odes that define them. You need to use some graphing CAS. Good luck!
